# Is there a better way to get the group with the largest value in one column?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am looking for a more elegant solution to getting a list of only winners (max votes) for each pandas group.

I have downloaded [California election results](https://github.com/openelections/openelections-data-ca) and procured the data that I want to use in a function called `create_df`.

```py
df = create_df()
df.head()
```

```
    candidate   county  district    office      party   precinct    votes
0   JOHN COX    ALAMEDA NaN         GOVERNOR    REP     200100      49.0
1   JOHN COX    ALAMEDA NaN         GOVERNOR    REP     200200      55.0
2   JOHN COX    ALAMEDA NaN         GOVERNOR    REP     200300      26.0
3   JOHN COX    ALAMEDA NaN         GOVERNOR    REP     200600      28.0
4   JOHN COX    ALAMEDA NaN         GOVERNOR    REP     200700      35.0
```

My current implementation is like this:

```py
county_votes = df.query("office == 'GOVERNOR'")\
                 .groupby(["county", "party"], as_index=False)\
                 .votes.sum()
winners = county_votes.reindex(
    county_votes.groupby("county").votes.idxmax().values
)[["county", "party"]]

winner.head()
```

```
    county      party
0   ALAMEDA     DEM
2   ALPINE      DEM
5   AMADOR      REP
7   BUTTE       REP
9   CALAVERAS   REP
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `df.groupby().agg({['country','party] : 'max'})`

Answer (score 0):

I found another method, and it seems to be faster as well.

```py
%%timeit
county_votes = df.query("office == 'GOVERNOR'")\
    .groupby(["county", "party"], as_index=False)\
    .votes.sum()
county_votes.reindex(
    county_votes.groupby("county").votes.idxmax().values
)[["county", "party"]].head()
```

> 42.4 ms ± 97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```py
%%timeit
df.query("office == 'GOVERNOR'")\
    .groupby(["county", "party"], as_index=False)\
    .votes.sum()\
    .sort_values(['county', 'votes'], ascending=[True, False])\
    .drop_duplicates(subset="county").head()
```

> 31.6 ms ± 60.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)